# Prototype iOS app crashes without any trace

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ekeventstore

I have not been touching the code base for a prototype app for a while (for a few iOS upgrades, in fact). When I try to start it now in Xcode 8.0 beta with the most recent iOS simulator it crashes apparently briefly after `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

The main view controller’s `viewDidLoad()` never gets called. The crash apparently leaves no trace and an exception breakpoint for all exceptions is apparently ignored. It trouble might be something in relation to accessing `EKEventStore`.

How can I find out what is wrong and which line of source code causes the problem?

P.S. I've checked multiple related threads but did yet find an answer that is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns I had to several `Privacy` keys (e.g. `Privacy - Reminders Usage Description`) to `Info.plist` as suggested [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48959).